# Call Excel COM Addins functions using macro

Tags: excel, vba, automation, office-2007

How can I call a function defined in a COM Addin using excel macro ?
Basically I have created a Excel COM Addin which does some bunch of stuff.
Now I want to invoke this via excel macros.
Is it possible to do it ?

Or

Is it possible to install COM Addin using a macro ?

Answer (score 1):

You can reference COM libraries in the VBA editor by going to tools -> references (I think) then you can select (or browse for) whatever DLL you've created. When you've selected it there you can use the functions contained within in the usual way.

You should see a big list of libraries to select from.

When I've done VBA development in the past I normally end up using a few things like the Microsoft XML libraries through this method.

Comment: But this will create a new instance of the addin.
I want to call a function of addin already loaded into excel without creating its another instance